# Radio Buttons Not Submitting Data

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making a quiz-type application and created the form to submit answers. It all works well, the question_id and user_id get submitted to the database, but the content never goes through. It always shows as nil. I'm 99% sure the problem is with my form, so here it is:

```
  <%= form_for @respond do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :question_id, value: @q.id, :style => "position:absolute;left:3000px;" %>
    <%= f.text_field :user_id, value: current_user.id, :style => "position:absolute;left:3000px;" %>
      <% for @ans in Answer.all.where('question_id = ?', @q.id) %>
          <%= f.radio_button :content, @ans.content, :type => "radio", :name => "radios", :id => "radio#{@ans.id}"%>
          <label for="radio<%= @ans.id %>" class="btn-lg btn-secondary" style="width:100%;background-color:#eaeaea;margin-bottom:20px"><%= @ans.content %></label>
      <% end %>
      <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Submit", :class => "btn-lg btn-primary", :style => "width:100%;margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px;" %>
     </div>
  <% end %>
```

I'm probably just missing something juvenile, but it's beyond me at this point. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you specifying a `value` attribute for your radio buttons?

Comment: Can you please paste the output of your terminal after you submit the form?

Comment: Are you adding this parameter to your strong parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason being you have changed the name of radio button from `content` to `radios`
so if your are searching `params[:respond][:content]` it will result to `nil`, here you need to search `params[:respond][:radios]`.

However if you are using strong parameter and your field_name is also content then i would suggest you not to specify the name of radio button.

```
<%= f.radio_button :content, @ans.content, :type => "radio", :id =>"radio#{@ans.id}"%>
```

it automatically takes name of radio button as `content` you can see it by inspect element in browser

thanks

Comment: Perfect! I appreciate your help very much, and the explanation made sense. Thank you!